# How to change the caret color in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I want to change the caret blinking color in XCode, the default is black but now when I have a dark background I would rather have a white caret color.

Anyone that know how to change the caret color in XCode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In XCode 4 developer preview 2 you can set the caret color. Excellent! Go to Preferences -> Fonts & Colors and then change the "Cursor" color to the color you want.

Comment: Annoying that even Apple incorrectly refers to this as a cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your theme file, where is in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/

The key DVTSourceTextInsertionPointColor means "Cursor color"

like this:
DVTSourceTextInsertionPointColor
1 1 1 1